# Circular Dependency on References

Tags: dll, reference, dependencies

At this moment I have a dynamic abstract factory with a singleton implementation of the class Factory where I store all the factories. Every factory has it's own types which there can be created instances out.

Those factories also got the RegisterType methode which I have created in order to register types from outside this project (DLL).

I want to register a type from outside the project. But in order to do that, ProjectA and projectB has to know information about each other.

So my question is, how can projectA and projectB know about each other without getting this error "Circular Dependency on References".

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[This blog post from Steve Smith](http://ardalis.com/avoid-referencing-infrastructure-in-visual-studio-solutions) directly addresses your question I believe.</strike>

Re-reading your question, the link I posted is not relevant, as you are dealing with 2 projects.

With most projects (web, desktop, even most apis) you typically have a project that is your entry point, your other project should contain dependent code or infrastructure code, there should be no bi-directional couple of the 2 (or more) projects.

It might be appropriate to use an IoC framework and register your dependencies, you would do this in lets say ProjectA, and provide to your factories types from ProjectB.

Be sure to abstract by using interfaces when passing these factories (and other types) into ProjectB where the implementation resides from ProjectA, then these interfaces can sit in ProjectB and not need any backward dependency.